# How to set the values into some variables from different lists

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, variable-definitions

I have a list of Values and a list of variables. I want to set the Values into Variables.

Assume the following code:

```
Values = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
VariableS = {{x1, x2}, {x3, x4}, {x5, x6}};

VariableS[[1]] = Values[[1]];

FIntegrate = Integrate[f[x], {x, x1, x2}]
```

I want to use `{x1, x2}={1, 2}` and get `x1=1 and x2=2` and finally caculate the definite Integral`FIntegrate` .But I can not set the `x1=1 and x2=2`.

How can I to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
Values = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
VariableS = {{x1, x2}, {x3, x4}, {x5, x6}};

MapThread[Set, {VariableS, Values}, 2];
Integrate[Sin[x], {x, x1, x2}]
```

> ```
>  Cos[1] - Cos[2]
> ```

Your way is not working because `VariableS[[1]] = Values[[1]];` sets the value of the first element of `VariableS` not the symbol names stored there.